# Can you work in physics research with a data science degree?

Tags: career-path, physics, changing-fields, data-science

I just finished my first year studying physics but honestly I didn't like it at all. I started studying a day before every exam and skipped almost every class. However, I love physics, I read books at home, watch documentaries and research on my own. I think it is the most beautiful field of human knowledge, but I hate the way it is teached at university and I really prefer experimental physics over theoretical physics.

I'm also very interested on AI and data analysis, so I'm thinking of switching careers to data science.

Would it be possible to work in physics research with a degree on data science? (With physics reasearch I mean doing data analysis of experiments and observations in a research group, for example to map galaxies, to classify particle crashes from a particle accelerator, etc.)

I think studying data science may be the best option for me because with the marks I have on physics I won't be able to do research. But I think I will be able to excel at data science, I'm studying every day on my own and taking online course after online course.

So what do you think? I don't want to continue with the physics degree, but I don't want to “say goodbye” to physics forever. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you hate about the way physics is taught at uni? The format (lectures and exercise groups)? The theoretical methodology (and all the maths you have to learn)? Something else?

Comment: If you dislike first year general physics so much then you probably won't like "experimental" physics either. Reading/watching physics =/= doing physics. In general physics, most of what you do is physics problems. Guess what you'll be doing in physics research? Physics problems! I heavily suggest you revisit your work ethic before deciding you dislike a class. First, attend the actual class. Second, don't study a day before an exam for anything. Third, do not underestimate physics. It takes a long duration of time and perseverance before you can understand fully.

Comment: Whether possible or not, you seem to be planning ahead too far, which is likely lead to failure and disappointment. Studying is a highly formative phase and when you graduate, you will have far better insights into your preferences, skills, … The probability that going into physics remains your unchallenged Plan A is very low. Instead select a field of study where the topic itself motivates you to study, so you can get a degree, acquire skills, etc. in the first place. After that, new career perspectives will likely emerge without further ado.

Comment: Tbh it sounds like you enjoy *the idea of doing physics* more than you enjoy *actually doing physics*. What good is it that you "love physics" in theory when in practice you "didn't like [studying physics at university] at all"?

Comment: _"I started studying a day before every exam and skipped almost every class."_ I know that feeling all too well. Don't stay there, you are __not__ interested in physics, and that's a good thing to know just a year into your studies, as opposed to 5 years in. Of all the people I know who love physics, they like it regardless of how absurdly bland the lesson is delivered.

Comment: Just to warn you that learning about physics from popular science books has almost nothing to do with actual physics research, they couldn't be more different.  It's like studying a painting in a museum compared to the process of creating the painting.

Comment: @Tom: I'm tempted to say it's like [playing *Operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(game)) -- something I remember doing back in the mid 1960s -- as compared to working as an operating room doctor, but I suppose this comparison is actually somewhat of an overkill (pun intended).

Comment: Why not try looking through the citations at the bottom of this funded NSF project and see if these types of things appeal to you. I would agree though that it sounds like you don't like *academia* more than anything. Academia is in some ways rather repetitive and involves a lot of boring *work*. I am an academic in my mind, but I don't want to spend my time as a professional academic. Thus, I work in academia as staff.  Figure this out before you spend money on more degrees.
 NSF-funded AI Institute on Physics:  https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=2020295&HistoricalAwards=false

Comment: To add on to Passer By's comment, from your description, you are more interested in science communication than physics. Actual physics is not something you can learn by watching documentaries, but making those documentaries is something science communicators would do (and they would aim at a more general audience, not research-level physicists).

Comment: The way physics is taught is, for the most part, the way physics is done. If you are not enjoying your physics courses at university, you will not enjoy doing research in physics.

Comment: It's much easier to teach a physicist the subset of data science which they need to know in order to do data analysis for an experiment than it is to teach a data scientist (without a physics background) the physics necessary to stop them from making obvious (to a physicist) mistakes.

Comment: I think most university students feel like you - I certainly did - but what you have to realise is that ALL advanced study consists of a lot of hard, tedious work with things you can't for your life understand - until you have worked through the details and suddenly it seems rather simple. Computer science is going to be the same: lots of apparently meaningless theory and hard work - those are your 'letters and numbers', that you need for when you begin to do real work.

Comment: This isn't just for university students, its also for once you have your PhD and are doing research. One of the lessons i remember during my PhD was one of my supervisors taking me aside and going through my thousands of lines of code line by line testing it was doing what we thought it was doing over the course of several hours. I've done that recently to understand mathematical tools I use for physics, as well as understanding machine learning theory a few years after having finished my PhD.

Answer (score 40):

> However, I love physics, I read books at home, watch documentaries and
> research on my own.

Engaging with popular books and documentaries on physics can be exciting and inspiring, but it's almost completely unlike actually performing scientific research. Actually doing the research involves a lot of inescapable drudgery: obsessively going over complex chains of mathematical reasoning, debugging huge and perhaps obscurely written computer programs, hours spent aligning components on an optics table, etc. All stuff that has to be done, but may not provide the easy thrill that comes from reading about 'big ideas'.

A friend studying geology went on two research cruises in the south Pacific in their first two years of graduate school. Exciting! Exotic ports! Big picture conversations about geology in the mess! The next three years were spent in a sub-basement, looking through a microscope, picking out little bits of volcanic glass from crushed rock samples using tiny watercolor paintbrushes. Nature's secrets are frequently hidden behind curtains of unbearable tedium. I don't intend to be discouraging, but you can't just blow off the hard, boring bits of a subject.

> Would it be possible to work in physics research with a degree on data
> science?

Maybe? It wouldn't be an easy path unless you turn out to be an absolute star in data science. Most physics laboratories just use their grad students and post-docs do all the programming and data science work. As @anyon mentions in a comment, some of the very biggest centers like CERN and NASA *do* hire data science specialists. However, counting on that means narrowing your choices to a *very* few employers and geographic locations, and they still might expect you to have a significant formal background in physics or astronomy. It's my experience that the life sciences labs are bigger employers of data science and software staff than physics labs.

For the moment at least, data science does provide a lot of opportunities. If you find you like data science work, it might be a good choice. With some luck and flexibility you might eventually be able to land a spot in a physics research team. Just be aware that you are aiming at a tiny niche, and be prepared to pivot in other directions.

Comment: Based on my experience, I think you hit the nail on the head with "they still might expect you to have a significant formal background in physics or astronomy".

Comment: If you don't understand the physics, best case you're a coding monkey, not really doing anything or analysing anything (since you don't know what it means). That's assuming they don't just get one of their PhD students to do it in order to improve their programming skills/diversify their background.

Answer (score 10):

My close friend, a professor at a highly respected university, is in charge of a physics lab doing nano- and biotechnologies.  Having a wealth of experimental results to process, he is now seeking to hire a postdoc or a highly advanced PhD student proficient in big data. However, the professor has firmly stated that a candidate should have taken the intermediate-level courses in physics back in their undergraduate years. It doesn't matter for this professor if a candidate has a BS degree in physics or chemistry or engineering -- but (s)he absolutely must be educated in physics at the intermediate college level, at least.

This story is, of course, just one datapoint -- but, trust me, a representative one.

Comment: I'm looking for a career that will combine my physics degrees with my newly acquired passion for data science and web development. Would it be possible to share more info about this position?

Comment: @cconsta1 Please drop me an e-mail. You will find my address on my webpage, which is available at my profile here.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes (with reservations)

I would refer you primarily to this great answer on the topic of the "research computing" career path

https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/178616/173832

Many national labs and universities have dedicated groups of programmers that play a critical role in scientific research. This is more like being a techinician/lab worker than a post-doc. You write code for researchers, or help them improve their existing codebases and workflow.

This is becoming an increasingly common and recognized career path, see e.g. the The [United States Research Software Engineer Association](https://us-rse.org/)

Source: I work as a data scientist/scientific programmer in a small earth science research group

Comment: think the link to the answer may be broken?

Comment: thanks @ACarter! Fixed

Answer (score 4):

## No

I've spent around 12 years in university studying/working in physics and if you didn't study it, there's no way you'll ever work in it professionally. It is an insanely hard subject. Physics requires advanced mathematical skills and builds strongly on top of its own concepts, like Maths. You will have no success for example in electrodynamics, if you didn't already study classical mechanics for basic concepts like Lagrangians and Hamiltonians, let alone all the math required for doing calculus on vector fields, green functions, etc.

Frontline physics is HARD, for the very sole reason that if it were easy, it would have been done already. For example, data science would come in very handy in particle accelerators where you need to correlate datapoints quickly. But to get a basic understanding of relativistic scattering physics reallistically takes a masters degree in physics (5 years studying) and that's the "easy" textbook examples. If you already knew you'd want to focus on that, it could probably be done in 3, if you gave it all.

Physics is a really competetive field, with lots of PhD students and less post doc let alone permanent positions. Not to take away from data science, but at the end of the day, it's math, and physicists are good at applied math. I don't see any reason why a PI would choose a non-physicist over a physicist.